Parsing Multiline Azure AKS logs to Elastic with Fluent Bit
I’m currently using Fluent Bit version 3.1.8-amd64 for log forwarding from Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) to Elasticsearch. I’m encountering issues with properly configuring Fluent Bit’s multiline parsing for logs. The challenge is that many of the logs generated in the AKS environment span multiple lines, and Fluent Bit doesn’t seem to correctly aggregate these into a single event before forwarding to Elasticsearch.
I’ve already tried configuring the multiline.parser option, but I’m still seeing log events split across multiple entries in Elasticsearch, which is impacting our ability to search and analyze logs effectively.
This is my conf file, thank you in advance
config:

service: |
[SERVICE]
    Flush 1
    Log_Level info
    parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server On
    HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port {{ .Values.metricsPort }}

inputs: |
[INPUT]
    Name                    tail
    Path                    /var/log/containers/*klix-api*.log
    Tag                     kube.*
    read_from_head          true
    multiline.parser        cri
    Skip_Long_Lines         On
    Skip_Empty_Lines        On
    Refresh_Interval        10
    Buffer_Chunk_Size       5M
    Buffer_Max_Size         5M
    Mem_Buf_Limit           100m
    
    
    

filters: |
[FILTER]
    Name                  multiline
    Match                 *
    Multiline.key_content log
    Multiline.parser      multiline-regex

#[FILTER]
#    Name          nest
#    Match         kube.*
#    Operation     lift
#    Nested_under  kubernetes
#    Add_prefix    kubernetes_
#    
#[FILTER]
#    Name          nest
#    Match         kube.*
#    Operation     lift
#    Nested_under  kubernetes_labels
#    Add_prefix    kubernetes_labels_

outputs: |
[OUTPUT]
    Name stdout                
    Match *                    


    

customParsers: |
[PARSER]
    Name        cri
    Format      regex
    Regex       ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<log>.*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z

[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-regex
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    rule        "start_state"  "^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})(.*)$"     "cont"
    rule        "cont"         "^(?!(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}))(.*)$" "cont"

'''
